# flexbox parent smaller than child elements on browser resize

Tags: html, css, flexbox

Why is the parent smaller than the children on narrow screens?

See snippet... then resize your browser (width-wise) to be smaller than the pink box. The scroll bars should appear. Scroll back to the right on the page and note the green background is smaller than the pink area and there is a white spot on the right.

[image]

So few questions:

1. Why does it happen?
2. How do I prevent the parent div's green background from getting smaller than the pink box/div when the browser is resized **without** setting an explicit width on the parent (or anywhere else) or using `overflow:hidden`?
3. Is there a flexbox solution to this problem?

Thanks,

Thomas

```css
.parent {
  height: 400px;
  background-color: green;
  display: flex;
}

.item {

  height: 100px;
  background-color: pink;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="item">looooooooooooooooooooooooooooong</div>
  <div class="item">looooooooooooooooooooooooooooong</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

1. It happens, because your `.parent` is a normal block element (flex is also a block-level container) and that is initialized with `width:auto;`, which is in your case the width of the viewport. So scrolling to the right will show white space because your div's width is smaller than the whole scrollable area.
2. You do that with setting the `.parent` to an inline element, which will respond to its childrens width.
3. Yes, just use `display: inline-flex;` on the `.parent`.

```css
.parent {
  height: 400px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: green;
  display: inline-flex;
}

.item {
  flex: 1;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: pink;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="item">looooooooooooooooooooooooooooong</div>
  <div class="item">looooooooooooooooooooooooooooong</div>
</div>
```

See [`display` on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/display).

Comment: I so love you right now :) Thank you. This was driving me mad.

Comment: I want to add that inline-flex collapses the parent to match the children but if you want the parent to be full width add min-width: 100% to parent. See http://codepen.io/_thomas/pen/vKbkXZ I tried width: 100% and it doesn't work.

Comment: Just add `flex:1;` to the `.item` - answer updated with `width:100%`.

Comment: Why the downvote? Dear downvoter, please explain where my answer is incorrect or misleading.

Comment: code snippet still overhanging the green box...

Comment: @mix3d which browser do you use?

Answer (score 20):

Flex items, by default, cannot be smaller than the size of their content. Therefore, while the parent can shrink, the flex items cannot shrink past the length of the text. This causes the overflow and, as a result, the column of white space below.

The initial setting on flex items is `min-width: auto`. In order for each item to stay within the container, switch to `min-width: 0`.

```css
.parent {
  height: 400px;
  background-color: green;
  display: flex;
}

.item {
  height: 100px;
  background-color: pink;
  padding: 10px;
  min-width: 0;   /* NEW */
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="item">looooooooooooooooooooooooooooong</div>
  <div class="item">looooooooooooooooooooooooooooong</div>
</div>
```

Now the pink boxes are not overflowing the container anymore.

However, the text is now overflowing the pink boxes.

The question doesn't specify behavior for the text, but here's one possible solution:

```css
.parent {
  height: 400px;
  background-color: green;
  display: flex;
}

.item {
  height: 100px;
  background-color: pink;
  padding: 10px;
  min-width: 0;            /* NEW */
  text-overflow: ellipsis; /* NEW */
  white-space: nowrap;     /* NEW */
  overflow: hidden;        /* NEW */      
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="item">looooooooooooooooooooooooooooong</div>
  <div class="item">looooooooooooooooooooooooooooong</div>
</div>
```