# CSS: Scroll container horizontally instead of page? (display: grid break)

Tags: css

I'm trying to get the cyan box to scroll horizontally instead of triggering a horizontal scrollbar on the page.

It seems to break when I try using a grid layout; I had to horizontally scrolling before when I didn't use a grid.

How can I fix this? `.page-wrap` should fill the whole window and add *vertical* scrollbar as needed. Only the `.box`s should scroll horizontally.

```css
html {
  overflow: hidden;
}

.page-wrap {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-areas:
    "sidebar main"
    "footer footer";
  grid-template-columns: 250px 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: auto 60px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  overflow: auto;
}

.sidebar {
  background-color: green;
  grid-area: sidebar;
}

.footer {
  background-color: red;
  grid-area: footer;
}

.main {
  background-color: yellow;
  grid-area: main;
}

.box {
  background-color: cyan;
  margin: 10px;
  overflow-x: scroll;
}
```

```html
<div class="page-wrap">
  <div class="sidebar">sidebar</div>
  <div class="main">
    <div class="box">

      <table>

        <tr>
          <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Veritatis, modi laudantium facilis. Cum quasi dolore quam doloribus reprehenderit illum nostrum id quas ea. Nostrum adipisci dolor nulla veniam exercitationem ipsa.</td>
          <td>Accusamus deserunt voluptatibus rem, aspernatur enim dolores, amet illum accusantium! Tempora, repellendus, fuga. Ex, consectetur mollitia reprehenderit qui, consequuntur ipsam maiores excepturi sapiente tempore odit repudiandae facere incidunt! Vero, beatae.</td>
          <td>Et minus eaque corrupti voluptas, earum ex non similique. Officiis a dignissimos veritatis quas provident sunt? Fuga vel officia qui, numquam eos sint, totam aspernatur, commodi quis, temporibus animi excepturi!</td>
          <td>Natus quaerat, sint nemo quia laudantium dolorem asperiores deserunt neque porro esse iusto reprehenderit et assumenda ipsum saepe consequuntur soluta officiis illum maiores cumque quos voluptate expedita tenetur eum autem!</td>
          <td>Asperiores ducimus accusantium aliquid nemo aliquam fugiat culpa maxime repudiandae pariatur minus. Eum incidunt iste molestias officiis sunt nostrum facilis velit. Reprehenderit quis aut officia quas beatae assumenda esse asperiores.</td>
          <td>Architecto, nam consequuntur odit distinctio! Suscipit fuga nam reprehenderit, nostrum modi provident iusto aperiam alias qui. Optio repudiandae reiciendis, omnis esse maiores! A blanditiis ducimus voluptate nobis exercitationem. Temporibus, vel!</td>
          <td>Similique et est omnis fuga, ad earum sapiente. Nam qui est quidem. Dignissimos amet harum voluptate a, sint culpa autem et neque, natus quod cum eos laudantium molestias, dolorem optio.</td>
          <td>Saepe aspernatur consequuntur sint nisi dolores nihil ab repudiandae, odio dolor, assumenda culpa corporis fugiat ullam officia quibusdam eaque enim, harum voluptatem eveniet reprehenderit natus consectetur deleniti nesciunt et! Omnis!</td>
          <td>Nihil quas quod numquam ut fugiat doloremque repudiandae animi iusto. Ullam quidem ipsa dolorem quos veritatis adipisci quisquam obcaecati culpa et consequatur, aspernatur unde eligendi rerum labore ab odit asperiores.</td>
          <td>Hic, aliquam, harum? Harum tempora accusantium animi ratione id perspiciatis quasi maiores iste odio quisquam, adipisci, laudantium cupiditate voluptatem mollitia soluta sunt eveniet facere quibusdam aspernatur? Suscipit obcaecati dolorum eligendi.</td>
          <td>Possimus natus, dignissimos vero nesciunt cum voluptatibus reiciendis commodi maxime voluptates qui illo quia distinctio tempora perferendis fugit modi itaque, quis recusandae quisquam quos ullam alias! Voluptatum repellat mollitia incidunt.</td>
          <td>Quod in ducimus, saepe obcaecati, eius vero ipsa ea cum reprehenderit velit sunt numquam eaque sapiente dolorem, possimus id nostrum natus eligendi accusamus nulla voluptatibus necessitatibus harum vitae. Dolorum, praesentium.</td>
          <td>Ab iusto, dicta deleniti explicabo perspiciatis pariatur deserunt blanditiis vel accusantium. Tempore architecto fugit cum similique laudantium et veritatis id, quos deleniti eaque voluptatum laboriosam, natus commodi itaque veniam vel.</td>
          <td>Dignissimos, quis excepturi, ratione nemo minima tenetur possimus. Quos eum placeat veniam voluptas, tempora, aliquam? Dolores ipsum obcaecati nisi itaque dolor, officiis quidem minima, nesciunt molestias facilis cupiditate repellat sequi.</td>
          <td>Dolores asperiores quidem totam illo veniam! Natus architecto nulla et asperiores modi quaerat, sed! Quam cum rem voluptatibus, rerum pariatur deserunt fugit odit, totam blanditiis animi nulla nisi facilis saepe.</td>
          <td>Quibusdam dolor explicabo soluta adipisci est quis aliquam tempora non, sint laudantium tempore minima inventore dolorum magni ad a rem magnam dignissimos expedita maxime numquam voluptas facere, quidem harum aliquid.</td>
          <td>Facere dolorem, ullam quasi. Numquam alias maiores harum voluptate delectus quos totam architecto voluptatum, sapiente pariatur modi, autem culpa omnis facere commodi unde assumenda. Quaerat, rem deserunt. Beatae, voluptates, cum.</td>
          <td>Magni pariatur eos quo perspiciatis ipsam a modi accusantium nulla fugiat officiis dolor ducimus hic, provident eius facilis quibusdam molestiae quasi, sunt, quis repellat nesciunt! Enim ipsum ducimus cumque placeat?</td>
          <td>Recusandae porro, consectetur placeat, temporibus delectus nesciunt aliquid nam incidunt at ipsa accusantium hic maxime tempora dolorum! Totam reiciendis, consequatur deserunt eveniet natus, vitae ipsa voluptate repudiandae velit, quia aspernatur!</td>
          <td>Et iusto ab repellat quae? Quas, ratione sapiente a, fuga voluptates, unde ullam dolores, fugit sint magnam perferendis ad quae. Magnam consequatur nisi quisquam, maiores quasi qui provident similique nobis.</td>
          <td>Ab qui hic, incidunt consequuntur officia exercitationem laboriosam suscipit veritatis est deleniti, debitis reiciendis at quidem consequatur iure ut quisquam tempore delectus aut soluta sequi tenetur sed magnam nostrum. Ab?</td>
          <td>Earum quis perspiciatis perferendis, rem, fugit cumque reiciendis! Porro consequatur quam consequuntur quaerat, atque praesentium adipisci fugit, dignissimos, ab labore reprehenderit provident temporibus, totam magnam illum pariatur deserunt alias cum!</td>
          <td>Officiis sit quam vero nobis doloribus necessitatibus possimus. Veniam, totam! Illo magnam, ipsum consequuntur at, ipsam sit fuga rerum architecto eum libero officiis, nobis! Obcaecati incidunt, mollitia placeat eaque atque.</td>
          <td>Nisi nam assumenda laudantium quos non quasi. Fuga enim, voluptatibus possimus tempora numquam dolores maiores, eum quaerat sit odit distinctio saepe optio aut accusamus explicabo, dolorem quidem consequatur. Maxime, similique!</td>
          <td>Autem inventore expedita quibusdam ipsum. Consequuntur nulla in vero blanditiis deleniti dignissimos, earum eligendi voluptatibus, minus illo, perspiciatis doloremque nisi sed maiores tempora. Excepturi minima, officia incidunt vitae pariatur illo!</td>
          <td>Sequi delectus dolorum, ea rem quis voluptatem accusantium quibusdam suscipit corrupti est laborum adipisci tenetur optio expedita inventore quam molestiae cupiditate totam. Rem sed, odit blanditiis eius quia vel eos.</td>
          <td>Vero dolor nam quisquam reiciendis quibusdam id sapiente quia est veritatis facilis, expedita recusandae sequi iste tempora harum illum nihil. Amet laborum, accusamus soluta dolores et iure? Possimus, et? Iusto.</td>
          <td>Ullam ipsum blanditiis obcaecati, rem aliquam voluptates fuga quo praesentium quia cum dignissimos debitis laboriosam itaque? Nostrum explicabo quae, rem praesentium accusantium dicta officia veritatis magni earum officiis. Inventore, ut.</td>
          <td>Quisquam, ex, dolore. Voluptates porro eum, blanditiis ullam non sequi suscipit iste eius! Soluta, nam quia impedit veritatis laudantium id ea iure autem magnam sapiente, a modi omnis. Optio, animi!</td>
          <td>Consequuntur amet, tenetur quidem consequatur doloremque distinctio ipsum minima, incidunt, fuga voluptatibus placeat quae autem recusandae quasi. Nihil, dolorum? Aliquid eligendi hic expedita saepe recusandae suscipit tempora tempore illum tenetur.</td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="footer">footer</div>
</div>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out.

```css
html {
  overflow: hidden;
}

.page-wrap {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-areas:
    "sidebar main"
    "footer footer";
  grid-template-columns: 250px 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: auto 60px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  overflow-x: auto;
}

.sidebar {
  background-color: lime;
  grid-area: sidebar;
}

.footer {
  background-color: orange;
  grid-area: footer;
}

.main {
  background-color: yellow;
  grid-area: main;
   min-width: 0;
}

.box {
  background-color: cyan;
  margin: 10px;
  overflow-x: scroll;
  max-width: 100%;
 
}
```

```html
<div class="page-wrap">
  <div class="sidebar">sidebar</div>
  <div class="main">
    <div class="box">
      <table>
        <tr>
          <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Veritatis, modi laudantium facilis. Cum quasi dolore quam doloribus reprehenderit illum nostrum id quas ea. Nostrum adipisci dolor nulla veniam exercitationem ipsa.</td>
          <td>Accusamus deserunt voluptatibus rem, aspernatur enim dolores, amet illum accusantium! Tempora, repellendus, fuga. Ex, consectetur mollitia reprehenderit qui, consequuntur ipsam maiores excepturi sapiente tempore odit repudiandae facere incidunt! Vero, beatae.</td>
          <td>Et minus eaque corrupti voluptas, earum ex non similique. Officiis a dignissimos veritatis quas provident sunt? Fuga vel officia qui, numquam eos sint, totam aspernatur, commodi quis, temporibus animi excepturi!</td>
          <td>Natus quaerat, sint nemo quia laudantium dolorem asperiores deserunt neque porro esse iusto reprehenderit et assumenda ipsum saepe consequuntur soluta officiis illum maiores cumque quos voluptate expedita tenetur eum autem!</td>
          <td>Asperiores ducimus accusantium aliquid nemo aliquam fugiat culpa maxime repudiandae pariatur minus. Eum incidunt iste molestias officiis sunt nostrum facilis velit. Reprehenderit quis aut officia quas beatae assumenda esse asperiores.</td>
          <td>Architecto, nam consequuntur odit distinctio! Suscipit fuga nam reprehenderit, nostrum modi provident iusto aperiam alias qui. Optio repudiandae reiciendis, omnis esse maiores! A blanditiis ducimus voluptate nobis exercitationem. Temporibus, vel!</td>
          <td>Similique et est omnis fuga, ad earum sapiente. Nam qui est quidem. Dignissimos amet harum voluptate a, sint culpa autem et neque, natus quod cum eos laudantium molestias, dolorem optio.</td>
          <td>Saepe aspernatur consequuntur sint nisi dolores nihil ab repudiandae, odio dolor, assumenda culpa corporis fugiat ullam officia quibusdam eaque enim, harum voluptatem eveniet reprehenderit natus consectetur deleniti nesciunt et! Omnis!</td>
          <td>Nihil quas quod numquam ut fugiat doloremque repudiandae animi iusto. Ullam quidem ipsa dolorem quos veritatis adipisci quisquam obcaecati culpa et consequatur, aspernatur unde eligendi rerum labore ab odit asperiores.</td>
          <td>Hic, aliquam, harum? Harum tempora accusantium animi ratione id perspiciatis quasi maiores iste odio quisquam, adipisci, laudantium cupiditate voluptatem mollitia soluta sunt eveniet facere quibusdam aspernatur? Suscipit obcaecati dolorum eligendi.</td>
          <td>Possimus natus, dignissimos vero nesciunt cum voluptatibus reiciendis commodi maxime voluptates qui illo quia distinctio tempora perferendis fugit modi itaque, quis recusandae quisquam quos ullam alias! Voluptatum repellat mollitia incidunt.</td>
          <td>Quod in ducimus, saepe obcaecati, eius vero ipsa ea cum reprehenderit velit sunt numquam eaque sapiente dolorem, possimus id nostrum natus eligendi accusamus nulla voluptatibus necessitatibus harum vitae. Dolorum, praesentium.</td>
          <td>Ab iusto, dicta deleniti explicabo perspiciatis pariatur deserunt blanditiis vel accusantium. Tempore architecto fugit cum similique laudantium et veritatis id, quos deleniti eaque voluptatum laboriosam, natus commodi itaque veniam vel.</td>
          <td>Dignissimos, quis excepturi, ratione nemo minima tenetur possimus. Quos eum placeat veniam voluptas, tempora, aliquam? Dolores ipsum obcaecati nisi itaque dolor, officiis quidem minima, nesciunt molestias facilis cupiditate repellat sequi.</td>
          <td>Dolores asperiores quidem totam illo veniam! Natus architecto nulla et asperiores modi quaerat, sed! Quam cum rem voluptatibus, rerum pariatur deserunt fugit odit, totam blanditiis animi nulla nisi facilis saepe.</td>
          <td>Quibusdam dolor explicabo soluta adipisci est quis aliquam tempora non, sint laudantium tempore minima inventore dolorum magni ad a rem magnam dignissimos expedita maxime numquam voluptas facere, quidem harum aliquid.</td>
          <td>Facere dolorem, ullam quasi. Numquam alias maiores harum voluptate delectus quos totam architecto voluptatum, sapiente pariatur modi, autem culpa omnis facere commodi unde assumenda. Quaerat, rem deserunt. Beatae, voluptates, cum.</td>
          <td>Magni pariatur eos quo perspiciatis ipsam a modi accusantium nulla fugiat officiis dolor ducimus hic, provident eius facilis quibusdam molestiae quasi, sunt, quis repellat nesciunt! Enim ipsum ducimus cumque placeat?</td>
          <td>Recusandae porro, consectetur placeat, temporibus delectus nesciunt aliquid nam incidunt at ipsa accusantium hic maxime tempora dolorum! Totam reiciendis, consequatur deserunt eveniet natus, vitae ipsa voluptate repudiandae velit, quia aspernatur!</td>
          <td>Et iusto ab repellat quae? Quas, ratione sapiente a, fuga voluptates, unde ullam dolores, fugit sint magnam perferendis ad quae. Magnam consequatur nisi quisquam, maiores quasi qui provident similique nobis.</td>
          <td>Ab qui hic, incidunt consequuntur officia exercitationem laboriosam suscipit veritatis est deleniti, debitis reiciendis at quidem consequatur iure ut quisquam tempore delectus aut soluta sequi tenetur sed magnam nostrum. Ab?</td>
          <td>Earum quis perspiciatis perferendis, rem, fugit cumque reiciendis! Porro consequatur quam consequuntur quaerat, atque praesentium adipisci fugit, dignissimos, ab labore reprehenderit provident temporibus, totam magnam illum pariatur deserunt alias cum!</td>
          <td>Officiis sit quam vero nobis doloribus necessitatibus possimus. Veniam, totam! Illo magnam, ipsum consequuntur at, ipsam sit fuga rerum architecto eum libero officiis, nobis! Obcaecati incidunt, mollitia placeat eaque atque.</td>
          <td>Nisi nam assumenda laudantium quos non quasi. Fuga enim, voluptatibus possimus tempora numquam dolores maiores, eum quaerat sit odit distinctio saepe optio aut accusamus explicabo, dolorem quidem consequatur. Maxime, similique!</td>
          <td>Autem inventore expedita quibusdam ipsum. Consequuntur nulla in vero blanditiis deleniti dignissimos, earum eligendi voluptatibus, minus illo, perspiciatis doloremque nisi sed maiores tempora. Excepturi minima, officia incidunt vitae pariatur illo!</td>
          <td>Sequi delectus dolorum, ea rem quis voluptatem accusantium quibusdam suscipit corrupti est laborum adipisci tenetur optio expedita inventore quam molestiae cupiditate totam. Rem sed, odit blanditiis eius quia vel eos.</td>
          <td>Vero dolor nam quisquam reiciendis quibusdam id sapiente quia est veritatis facilis, expedita recusandae sequi iste tempora harum illum nihil. Amet laborum, accusamus soluta dolores et iure? Possimus, et? Iusto.</td>
          <td>Ullam ipsum blanditiis obcaecati, rem aliquam voluptates fuga quo praesentium quia cum dignissimos debitis laboriosam itaque? Nostrum explicabo quae, rem praesentium accusantium dicta officia veritatis magni earum officiis. Inventore, ut.</td>
          <td>Quisquam, ex, dolore. Voluptates porro eum, blanditiis ullam non sequi suscipit iste eius! Soluta, nam quia impedit veritatis laudantium id ea iure autem magnam sapiente, a modi omnis. Optio, animi!</td>
          <td>Consequuntur amet, tenetur quidem consequatur doloremque distinctio ipsum minima, incidunt, fuga voluptatibus placeat quae autem recusandae quasi. Nihil, dolorum? Aliquid eligendi hic expedita saepe recusandae suscipit tempora tempore illum tenetur.</td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="footer">footer</div>
</div>
```

I remembered [an annoying quirk](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38937653/65387) with flexbox, thought it might apply to grid too.

The trick is to add `min-width: 0` to `.main`.