# align items: center hide tags

Tags: html, css

I have a problem with `display: flex, align-items: center`

This is my html file and CSS file:

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: 'Kumbh Sans', sans-serif;
}

.navbar {
  background: #131313;
  height: 80px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.navbar__item {
  background: yellow;
}

.navbar__link {
  border: 2px solid red;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="navbar">
    <div class="nav__container">
      <a href="/" id="navbar__logo">NEXT</a>
      <div class="navbar__toggle" id="mobile-menu">
        <span class="bar"></span>
        <span class="bar"></span>
        <span class="bar"></span>
      </div>
      <ul class="navbar__menu">
        <li class="navbar__item">
          <a href="/" class="navbar__link">Home</a>
        </li>
        <li class="navbar__item">
          <a href="/" class="navbar__link">Tech</a>
        </li>
        <li class="navbar__item">
          <a href="/" class="navbar__link">Products</a>
        </li>
        <li class="navbar__item">
          <a href="/" class="navbar__link">Sign Up</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

I spent the whole afternoon looking for the answer, but haven't fount it yet.

The first, some items in the **class =  narbar__menu** be hide, i dont know why, i comment **align-item: center** in **.navbar** of css file and it comes back. After I read about display: flex, but i still can't explain

The second, i uncomment **align-item: center** in **.navbar** of css file and i crease the value of **height** in **.navbar** to **100px**, the items are not hide anymore.

Those are two things I don't understand, please explain to me

I already read

[align-items: center makes img disappear](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47275700/align-items-center-makes-img-disappear)

[How to horizontally center an element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/114543/how-to-horizontally-center-an-element?answertab=scoredesc#tab-top)

I appreciate any help for me, thank you very much.

Comment: Why are you limiting the height of the navbar to 80px here to begin with? Your navigation items, in sum, are clearly higher than that.

Answer (score 0):

Your .navbar class is the outter most layer of your nav. Setting a display: 'whatever' there, is only resposible for the child element, in this case .nav__container. So you just centering the .nav__container. Not the content inside .nav__container. Try setting `display: flex` on the nav container class and play around this way. But keep in mind this will center all the content inside (you have 3 children inside of it). Also, when you want to set a `display: flex` on something most of the times you will also need a `width: 100%` or `width: 100vw`, depending on the situation.

As far as your `<ul>` tag, lists by default are vertical. Try this:

```
.navbar__menu {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center; // Main axis alignment
  justfy-content: flex-start; // Secondary axis alignment
  flex-direction: row; // sets the list to be horizontal, so that it does not hide
  gap: 0 1rem; // Sets a gap between your items in the list, first value is for top & bottom, second value for left & right.
  list-style: none; // Makes the dots of the list dissapear.
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Finally, I found the answer.

In my opiniion, when we use flex box, the weight, hight of all flex items is auto, i mean, is set equal to the height and width of the content. So, when i change height of the .navbar than the height of all flex elements, it appear in full.On the contrary, it will miss some items.

The best way is to set **min-weight: 0**, **min-height: 0**, depending on the case of you

I dont know, Am i right? I really hope everybody can review it for me

Thank you so much!

Some links, i already read

https://dfmcphee.com/flex-items-and-min-width-0/
[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40407619/min-width-rendering-differently-in-
flex-direction-row-and-flex-direction-colum](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40407619/min-width-rendering-differently-in-flex-direction-row-and-flex-direction-colum)

[Why don't flex items shrink past content size?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36247140/why-dont-flex-items-shrink-past-content-size)

[flexbox parent smaller than child elements on browser resize](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38937376/flexbox-parent-smaller-than-child-elements-on-browser-resize)